# How to tell what ember-cli / Broccoli is doing behing the scenes?

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I have a `Brocfile.js` which tells Broccoli / ember-cli to get a bunch of files, do something with them, and produce and output (`vendor.css`, `vendor.js`, `app.js`, `app.css`, or something else)

How can I turn-on debugging for ember-cli so that I know what is doing with which files, at each step?

The reason I need this is because my `vendor.css` is incomplete but I do not know exactly what is missing: I would like to follow the process that Broccoli is running to compare it with my Brocfile specification, and see where the mistake could be ...

I have tried with `--verbose`. with no luck:

```
» ember server --verbose
version: 0.1.11
The option '--verbose' is not registered with the serve command. Run `ember serve --help` for a list of supported options.
```